# What is navigation.json in Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just tried out Android Studio 4.1 today. I started the Android Studio and created empty activity and I run it using the android virtual device. Then it was failed and this error is shown:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
> File 'E:\Project\AndroidLayout\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.
```

When I rebuild the project, the error message is shown here:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Project\AndroidLayout\app\build\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Note that this is fresh install and fresh project without any modification in the code.

**UPDATE 1:**

1. Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4w_NOA_UVQ
2. Bug Report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170720311

**UPDATE 2:**

After I downgrade the Android Gradle Plugin version from 4.1.0 to 4.0.2 and the Gradle version from 6.5 to 6.4.1 now it is working.
So my conclusion is there is a bug in the Android Gradle Plugin 4.1.+ and Gradle 6.5.+.

Comment: Does creating another project throws same error? Or was this just one time thing?

Comment: Yes, I have tried many times. Here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4w_NOA_UVQ

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find a temporary solution:

After I downgrade the Android Gradle Plugin version from 4.1.0 to 4.0.2 and the Gradle version from 6.5 to 6.4.1 now it is working. So my conclusion is there is a bug in the Android Gradle Plugin 4.1.+ and Gradle 6.5.+.

In order to downgrade, just go to File -> Project Structure.

Comment: This issue seems to have been fixed in Gradle Plugin version 4.1.1, but I found it occurs again with version 4.1.2. Downgrading to 4.1.1 solved it for me.

Comment: Upgrading the Android Gradle Plugin to 4.2.2 and the Gradle Version to the second latest worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Had same issue.  Moving project files to ntfs drive fixed it.

Comment: Hi, it's a good idea to try to add more information, link to tutorials or provide more context.

Comment: I had the project file on a usb drive that is exFAT formatted and the project would encounter build error.  I moved the same project files onto a usb drive that is NTFS formatted and the project has no build error and runs.

Comment: Nice discovery. I am having the problem and I checked that my hard drive IS indeed exFAT partition. I can't reformat it to NTFS though as I have to back up the files first.

Comment: It works here too! (Android Studio 4.1, Windows 10)

Comment: this is true. ok. but why? what if I do want to work with exFAT only?

Answer (score 4):

### Downgrading the Android Gradle Plugin version from 4.1.0 to 4.0.2 and the Gradle version from 6.5 to 6.4.1 now it is working; works for me as well. Now app is no longer experiencing building errors.Thanks.
Error message was :

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').

> File 'F:\NietsPastApp\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

Comment: Actually, I found this solution first. I don't post it to the answer because I know that it is a temporary solution.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for help, downgrade it's ok. just for other who search the file :

gradle 4.0.2 change here : /build.gradle

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

gradle 6.4.1 : gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: It helped but I got the same things working on my other machine.. a bit weird

Answer (score 1):

File -> Project Structure. reduce your build tools version to 29
i tried it's work

Comment: maybe also have anorther issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case and for kotlin I have downgraded kotlin version from 1.4.32 to 1.4.31