# Android studio cannot find navigation.json

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to start my project for university and upon trying to build my project I am met with: "G:\4th Year Uni\Mobile Platform Development\Android Studio FIles\test\app\build\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json (The system cannot find the file specified)" has anyone else encountered this before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is navigation.json in Android Studio 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333649/what-is-navigation-json-in-android-studio-4-1)

Comment: perhaps this is relevant to you ?