# Android - Gradle build Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'

Tags: android, gradle

I had to upgrade Gradle to be able to use the latest LiveData version.

I'm getting this error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\projekte\ANDROID\Yolol\app\build\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

I also tried some other versions that are compatible with latest LiveData plugin but same crap happens.

How to solve this??

Ofc I looked up answers for same question but none of them are helping, at least not those I could find

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333649/what-is-navigation-json-in-android-studio-4-1) question has the answer to your issue.

Comment: This is what I did before I needed LiveData plugin which only works with higher gradle so downgrading isn't an option

Comment: Could you add information regarding your Android Studio version, the versions of the dependencies that you are using for LiveData and the gradle plugin versions? I'll try to reproduce the error with those.